# KafkaConsumer makes error on KafkaServer (ver 0.9.0.1)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to test Producer, Consumer with Kafka-Client library(0.9.0.1).
The broker(0.9.0.1) is running on the server and I have test KafkaProducer already , there was no problem.
But When I test **KafkaConsumer** for polling, the broker makes a error message.

> [2016-03-18 13:44:19,129] ERROR Closing socket for /172.26.132.149 because of error (kafka.network.Processor) 
>   kafka.common.KafkaException: Wrong request type 10
>           at kafka.api.RequestKeys$.deserializerForKey(RequestKeys.scala:57)
>           at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.(RequestChannel.scala:53)
>           at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:353)
>           at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:245)

The consumer test code is below.

```
class ConsumerRunner implements Runnable{
    private KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer;
    private String topic;
    public ConsumerRunner(String topic,Properties props){
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(props);
        this.topic = topic;
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(this.topic));
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            ConsumerRecords<String,String> records = consumer.poll(10000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                 System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
    }

}
```

I guessed the polling request contains wrong request type key, but when I checked Kafka core sources, and I relized The request type key '10' is defined as 'GroupCoordinatorKey'. I found suspicious codes in '**kafka.network.RequestChannel.scala**'

```
   val requestObj =
      if ( RequestKeys.keyToNameAndDeserializerMap.contains(requestId))
        RequestKeys.deserializerForKey(requestId)(buffer)

      else
        null
```

The test consumer also show the error message

> java.io.EOFException: null    at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:134)
>     at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:320)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:163)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorKnown(AbstractCoordinator.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:886)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:853)
>     at
>   com.medialog.mdt.kafka.KafkaTest$ConsumerThread.run(KafkaTest.java:61)

Does Anybody have an idea? Is it my problem? or others?
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Minkoo

Not sure if your just trying to just create a consumer for 0.9 Kafka code or your kafka messages have something specific that is causing this problem, can you share more details.

But if your just trying to write a kafka consumer for 0.9, then in Kafka 0.9 there is new consumer API. If your open to use the new consumer API  take a look at this sample https://github.com/sdpatil/KafkaAPIClient/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spnotes/kafka/simple/Consumer.java for sample.

Sunil